# How do you press the "use photo" button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, automation, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to make an app the takes pictures every so often with this code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var cameraIsOn = false

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var timeInterval = 15

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    }

    @IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        present(imagePicker, animated: true) {
            self.cameraIsOn = true
            self.imagePicker.takePicture()
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
        }

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true) {
                self.cameraIsOn = true

                if self.cameraIsOn {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(self.timeInterval * 60), execute: {
                    self.imagePicker.takePicture()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        cameraIsOn = false
    }
}
```

After a picture is taken. You are shown a "retake or use photo screen".

I am trying to press the "use photo" button programmatically so that I can complete the loop until someone presses cancel.

Comment: Could you be more clear on the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Here you go. I hope it is more easily understandable now.

Comment: Apple clearly states for takePicture() -"Calling this method when the source type of the image picker is set to a value other than UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera results in the throwing of an invalidArgumentException exception." Visit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619160-takepicture for more.

Comment: It is only like that so i can test the interface on a simulater

Answer (score -2):

Not sure of what button(use photo) action you are looking for! but to call/press a UIButton programmatically. Try this

yourButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

It would be better if you make your question more detailed. What is your scenario? What exactly you are tying to achieve?